# How to portably find out min(INT_MAX, abs(INT_MIN))?

Tags: c++, c, math, limits

How can I portably find out the smallest of `INT_MAX` and abs(`INT_MIN`)? (That's the mathematical absolute value of `INT_MIN`, not a call to the `abs` function.)

It should be as same as `INT_MAX` in most systems, but I'm looking for a more portable way.

Comment: @barakmanos: They're not the same; usually, `INT_MIN == -INT_MAX - 1`. I think it's actually UB to take `-INT_MIN` on such systems.

Comment: you mean the `abs` function 2's complement which returns the same type as the argument so `abs(INT_MIN) == INT_MIN` or abs in the mathematical sense, which might need a wider type to return the correct value of `min(INT_MAX, abs(INT_MIN))`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While the *typical* value of `INT_MIN` is -2147483648, and the *typical* value of `INT_MAX` is 2147483647, it is not guaranteed by the standard. TL;DR: The value you're searching for is `INT_MAX` in a conforming implementation. But *calculating* `min(INT_MAX, abs(INT_MIN))` isn't portable.

---

### The possible values of `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`

`INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are defined by the Annex E (Implementation limits) 1 (C standard, C++ inherits this stuff):

> The contents of the header  are given below, in alphabetical
>   order. The minimum magnitudes shown shall be replaced by
>   implementation-defined magnitudes with the same sign. The values shall
>   all be constant expressions suitable for use in #if preprocessing
>   directives. The components are described further in 5.2.4.2.1.
>
> [...]
>
> `#define INT_MAX +32767`
>
> `#define INT_MIN -32767`
>
> [...]

The standard requires the type `int` to be an integer type that can represent the range `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]` (section 5.2.4.2.1.).

Then, 6.2.6.2. (Integer types, again part of the C standard), comes into play and further restricts this to what we know as *two's or ones' complement*:

> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three
>   groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits;
>   signed char shall not have any padding bits. There shall be exactly one sign bit.
>   Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object
>   representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are M value bits in the signed
>   type and N in the unsigned type, then M ≤ N). If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the
>   following ways:
>
> — the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
>
> — the sign bit has the value −(2M) (two’s complement);
>
> — the sign bit has the value −(2M − 1) (ones’ complement).

Section 6.2.6.2. is also very important to relate the value representation of the signed integer types with the value representation of its unsigned siblings.

This means, you either get the range `[-(2^n - 1), (2^n - 1)]` or `[-2^n, (2^n - 1)]`, where `n` is *typically* 15 or 31.

### Operations on signed integer types

Now for the second thing: Operations on signed integer types, that result in a value that is not within the range `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]`, the behavior is undefined. This is explicitly mandated in C++ by Paragraph 5/4:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
>   representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

For C, 6.5/5 offers a very similar passage:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the
>   result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its
>   type), the behavior is undefined.

So what happens if the value of `INT_MIN` happens to be less than the negative of `INT_MAX` (e.g. -32768 and 32767 respectively)? Calculating `-(INT_MIN)` will be undefined, the same as `INT_MAX + 1`.

So we need to avoid ever calculating a value that may isn't in the range of `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]`. Lucky, `INT_MAX + INT_MIN` is always in that range, as `INT_MAX` is a strictly positive value and `INT_MIN` a strictly negative value. Hence `INT_MIN < INT_MAX + INT_MIN < INT_MAX`.

Now we can check, whether, `INT_MAX + INT_MIN` is equal to, less than, or greater than 0.

```
`INT_MAX + INT_MIN`  |  value of -INT_MIN    | value of -INT_MAX 
------------------------------------------------------------------
         < 0         |  undefined            | -INT_MAX
         = 0         |  INT_MAX = -INT_MIN   | -INT_MAX = INT_MIN
         > 0         |  cannot occur according to 6.2.6.2. of the C standard
```

Hence, to determine the minimum of `INT_MAX` and `-INT_MIN` (in the mathematical sense), the following code is sufficient:

```
if ( INT_MAX + INT_MIN == 0 )
{
    return INT_MAX; // or -INT_MIN, it doesn't matter
}
else if ( INT_MAX + INT_MIN < 0 )
{
    return INT_MAX; // INT_MAX is smaller, -INT_MIN cannot be represented.
}
else // ( INT_MAX + INT_MIN > 0 )
{
    return -INT_MIN; // -INT_MIN is actually smaller than INT_MAX, may not occur in a conforming implementation.
}
```

Or, to simplify:

```
return (INT_MAX + INT_MIN <= 0) ? INT_MAX : -INT_MIN;
```

The values in a ternary operator will only be evaluated if necessary. Hence, `-INT_MIN` is either left unevaluated (therefore cannot produce UB), or is a well-defined value.

Or, if you want an assertion:

```
assert(INT_MAX + INT_MIN <= 0);
return INT_MAX;
```

Or, if you want that at compile time:

```
static_assert(INT_MAX + INT_MIN <= 0, "non-conforming implementation");
return INT_MAX;
```

---

### Getting integer operations right (i.e. if correctness matters)

If you're interested in safe integer arithmetic, have a look at my [implementation of safe integer operations](http://ideone.com/bGClJX). If you want to see the patterns (rather than this lengthy text output) on which operations fail and which succeed, choose [this demo](http://ideone.com/p9FqHn).

Depending on the architecture, there may be other options to ensure correctness, such as gcc's option `-ftrapv`.

Comment: Note that the unevaluated _const-expr_ `-INT-MIN` has been specifically allowed since C++14.

Comment: ... and thus the code needn't compile on pre-C++14 implementations. I can't remember whether or not a diagnostic is required.

Comment: Actually Std C. 6.2.6.2 and its equivalent in C++ do constrain the representation so that INT_MAX must be 2^N-1 for some N and INT_MIN must be either -INT_MAX or -INT_MAX-1.

Comment: Could the `if` be replaced with an `#if` ?  Or does that run into issues around the preprocessor's integer representation not necessarily being the same as the compiler's?

Answer (score 9):

```
INT_MAX + INT_MIN < 0 ? INT_MAX : -INT_MIN
```

*Edited to add explanation:* Of course the difficulty is that `-INT_MIN` or `abs(INT_MIN)` will be undefined if `-INT_MIN` is too big to fit in an `int`. So we need some way of checking whether this is the case. The condition `INT_MAX + INT_MIN < 0` tests whether `-INT_MIN` is greater than `INT_MAX`. If it is, then `INT_MAX` is the smaller of the two absolute values. If not, then `INT_MAX` is the larger of the two absolute values, and `-INT_MIN` is the correct answer.

Comment: Actually, it's still not correct because `-INT_MIN` can't be represented in an `int`

Comment: @kdopen The branch with `-INT_MIN` is not evaluated then, which means UB doesn't happen.

Comment: `INT_MAX + INT_MIN` will evaluate to either 0 (sign and magnitude, one’s complement) or -1 (two’s complement).  In either case, the result have the value of  `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux See the answer by JeremyRoman: pre-C99, other representations were allowed.

Comment: Let me know of a C89 compliant platform where `INT_MAX + INT_MIN` does not have the values 0 nor -1 so I may award a bonus of +50 for this answer.

Comment: Even simpler would just be to compare `INT_MIN < -INIT_MAX`

Comment: @JensGustedt That makes an analogous assumption, that `-INT_MAX` is representable as an `int`.

Comment: @Brian On what implementation (real or hypothetical) is `-INT_MAX` not representable?

Comment: @milleniumbug Actually I reassert my original objection. Although the the branch with {{-INT_MIN}} in it won't be *executed*, it must still be *compiled*. Unless the compiler uses a larger data type (assumes {{sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)}}) to store the constant and then coerces it at run time, this should raise a compilation error on older C compilers.

Comment: @kdopen I see no reason why this should not compile. The compiler is not required to evaluate constant expressions at compile time. It may do so, but not if this would cause it to reject a conforming program. This expression follows all the rules. In C, a minus sign is not considered part of an integer constant.

Answer (score 7):

In C99 and above, `INT_MAX`.

Quoth the spec:

> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three
>   groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits;
>   signed char shall not have any padding bits. There shall be exactly one sign bit.
>   Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object
>   representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are M value bits in the signed
>   type and N in the unsigned type, then M ≤ N). If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect
>   the resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the
>   following ways:
>
> - the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
> - the sign bit has the value −(2^M) (two’s complement);
> - the sign bit has the value −(2^M − 1) (ones’ complement).

(Section 6.2.6.2 of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: Is that true in C89? That old but not dead language doesn't mandate one of those three representations.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I don't have a C89 spec at hand, but as you edited, this is true in C99.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: haccks: On C99 and above, the representation restriction prevents abs(INT_MIN) from being smaller than INT_MAX.

Comment: I know and OP does know it too. He is asking about how to find min of mathematical absolute value of `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Gilles C89 didn't specifically say 2sC 1sC S&M, but it did require "pure binary" except for the "highest" bit, which was obviously intended to mean the sign bit for signed but as written also formally allowed some limited weirdness in unsigned. AFAIK no machine used any signed representation satisfying "pure binary except sign" other than those three, and no implementor objected to this "clarification" in C99.

Comment: haccks: If abs(INT_MIN) >= INT_MAX (which you've agreed to), then min(INT_MAX, abs(INT_MIN)) == INT_MAX.

Answer (score 1):

On most systems, abs (INT_MIN) is not defined. For example, on typical 32 bit machines, INT_MAX = 2^31 - 1, INT_MIN = - 2^31, and abs (INT_MIN) cannot be 2^31.

Comment: This is not what the question asks. `abs(INT_MIN)` isn't portable — so how do you compute the absolute value of `INT_MIN`? If `INT_MAX` is -2^31, then abs(`INT_MAX`) *is* 2^31 — this is simple math. That number cannot be represented as an `int32_t`, so you need another way to compare it with `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

`-INT_MAX` is representable as an `int` in all C and C++ dialects, as far as I know. Therefore:

```
-INT_MAX <= INT_MIN ? -INT_MIN : INT_MAX
```

Answer (score -1):

`abs(INT_MIN)` will invoke undefined behavior. Standard says

#### 7.22.6.1 The `abs`, `labs` and `llabs` functions:

> The `abs`, `labs`, and `llabs` functions compute the absolute value of an integer `j`. If the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.

Try this instead  :
Convert `INT_MIN` to `unsignrd int`. Since -ve numbers can't be represented as an `unsigned int`, `INT_MAX` will be converted to `UINT_MAX + 1 + INT_MIN`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned min(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n", min(INT_MAX, INT_MIN));
}
```

Comment: This is no bad answer!

Comment: I didnt -1, I was just pointing out an error in an earlier revision. I will remove that now

Comment: Well it's still incorrect. `abs(INT_MIN)` _may_ be equal to INT_MAX, depending on the architecture. In that case it's clearly well-formed.

Comment: @stefan; Standard says its UB and that's it.

Comment: @haccks No, it does not. it does not force 2s or 1s complement.

Comment: @milleniumbug; Now it answers .

Comment: @haccks I posted my own answer as I was tired of explaining the same thing over and over again. Please tell me if there are things left unclear.

Comment: If UINT_MAX == INT_MAX (where INT_MAX == math_not_C_pow(2,num_magnitude_bits)-1) as is allowed but rare, and INT_MIN == -INT_MAX -1 as is allowed and common (for 2sC), b=(unsigned)(INT_MIN) yields 0 and is selected as the minimum, which is not the correct result.