# How to compare to numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()

Tags: c++, stl, int64, uint64, numeric-limits

Consider that the sign (`+1` or `-1`) is known and there is a code that parses unsigned integer. That unsigned integer can be equal to `-numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()`. How to correctly compare without triggering undefined behavior?

```
int8_t sign = /* +1 or -1 */;
uint64_t result = /* parse the remaining string as unsigned integer */;
if( result > uint64_t(numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()))
{
    if(sign == 1) return false; // error: out of range for int64_t
    // Is the below code correct or how to implement correctly its intent?
    if(result == uint64_t(-numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't this be the usual case:`abs(numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()) == numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()`? then the second if will never evaluate to true.

Comment: `-numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()` will miserably fail on most implementation since it will convert to something that is out of range (`-128` => `+128` for typical `int8`, which is not possible, so you'll probably get `0 `).

Comment: @m.s. In the usual case (2's complement) `abs(min) = max + 1`. When using ones' complement or sign-magnitude, `abs(min) = max`, and there is no problem, but this is the "esoteric" case.

Comment: @m.s., that is kind of my concern, but the following program stores correctly the negation of `numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()` in an `uint64_t`: https://ideone.com/uHIcCD . But that's just an example for that specific compiler, not a general rule.

Comment: If you are assuming Two's complement (looks like for me?), then you should simply remove one from `result` and compare it to `max`.

Comment: Wrong order of operations -> `-uint64_t(numeric_limits<int64_t>::min())`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, that way you would negate an unsigned integer. What do you expect to get?

Comment: @SergeRogatch Don't let Microsoft's idiotic warnings confuse you, negating an unsigned integer is a perfectly fine operation, modulo 2^bitsize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Holt, you're effectively assuming 2's complement arithmetic. Therefore, you can replace `-min` by `max+1`:

```
if(result == uint64_t(numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()) + 1)
```

This avoids the undefined behavior (signed integer overflow) that results when negating the minimal value.

It might be a good idea to verify your system really uses 2's complement (depends on how strictly you want to comply with the C++ standard). This can be achieved by comparing `-max` with `min`:

```
if (numeric_limits<int64_t>::max() + numeric_limits<int64_t>::min() == 0)
{
    // If not two's complement:
    // Too large absolute value == error, regardless of sign
    return false;

    // on all sane (2's complement) systems this will be optimized out
}
```

There are no possibilities for other relations between `min` and `max`; this is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809849/509868).

Comment: It seems the code you gave should return `false` rather than `true` because it's not possible to represent such negative value in case `-min`==`max`